# How to change background color of button if input field isnt empty

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, background-color

I made this code excerpt from my original code,and I'm having a lot of trouble with getting this to work.I got the script primarily from https://zellwk.com/blog/check-empty-input-js/. Though I am a complete begginer to html and jscript help would be much appreciated.

```
buttonlog[data-state="valid"] {
  background-color:#C9A243;
}

buttonlog[data-state="invalid"] {
  background-color:#909495;
}

<script>
const username = document.querySelector('username');

input.addEventListener('username', evt => {
  const value = username.value;
  
const password = document.querySelector('password')

input.addEventListener('password', evt => {
    const value1 = password.value;
  
  const trimmed = value.trim();
  const trimmed1 = value1.trim();
  
  if (trimmed.length()>5) {
    if(trimmed1.length()>3){
    buttonlog.dataset.state = 'valid';
  }} else {
    buttonlog.dataset.state = 'invalid';
  }
}})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Karlo and welcome to SO. *I'm having a lot of trouble with getting this to work*, could you be more precise? What does not work? What should it do? How are you trying to make it work? Walk us through it. Could you also include the related HTML? Thanks!

Comment: The question still needs some more detail, but from a quick review, the "length" property you used is not a function and should be used like this "trimmed.length" without the brackets

Comment: Hello Emiel,so basically this code is supposed to check if the user has input more than 5 characters into the username field and more than 3 characters into the password field.Once the conditions have been met it is supposed to turn the button background color to the specified color (this is under datastate "valid"),until this condition is met the background color of the button should be the color under datastate "invalid". I couldn't put entire code due to Stack Overflow not letting me for some reason

Comment: `<body>

<form>
<label>Username : </label>   
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" style="height:35px;"required>  
<label>  Password : </label>   
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" style="height:35px;" required>
<button id="buttonlog" type="submit" style="margin-left:117px;">Log in</button>
</form>
` This is the body of the code the only other thing currently in the code is the button css which shouldn't be important. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

## Doing this is quite simple, it requires no Javascript.

There is an attribute called 'pattern'. It takes a Regex value. You can check if the pattern is matched in CSS, so no Javascript is required.

Let's say you had an input, it would look like this:

```html
<input pattern="\d+" required>
```

That would match all digits (`\d+`). You can style it using CSS. If the pattern is matched, you would use `input:valid` to see if it's correct. If you wanna see if it's not correct, you could use `input:invalid`. Quite simple. The reason I have the 'required' attribute is because without it, it would still match if the textbox is completely empty.
Like this:
[image: Example]

Note that the CSS is:

```css
input:valid {
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Now, if we add required, we can see it's only visible when the regex is matched:[image: Example]

Here are some examples of it working:
[image: Example]
[image: Example]
[image: Example]

(The 'editor' I'm using is https://battledash-2.github.io/Live-IDE/ if you're wondering)

It's pretty simple to do. It only matches numbers, nothing else. If it's a number, it will be yellow. Otherwise, it will be the default. If you have any questions you can comment it :D

Just encase you wanted, here's a snippet:

```css
input:valid {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input pattern="\d+" required>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're still reading this, and that is not the answer you wanted and you are sure you want it with Javascript, I'll write another answer below:

#### 'password' isn't an event!

I can see you tried using `.addEventListener('password')`, but from my experience, that is not a thing. Even for password inputs, it's still `.addEventListener('input')`.

Try this code instead:

CSS:

```css
buttonlog[data-state="valid"] {
  background-color:#C9A243;
}

buttonlog[data-state="invalid"] {
  background-color:#909495;
}
```

and HTML/JS:

```html
<script>
const username = document.querySelector('username');

input.addEventListener('username', evt => {
  const value = username.value;
  
const password = document.querySelector('password')

input.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    const value1 = password.value;
  
  const trimmed = value.trim();
  const trimmed1 = value1.trim();
  
  if (trimmed.length()>5) {
    if(trimmed1.length()>3){ // I don't see a point on this second if, it's totally useless because if it's >5 it's obv >3
    buttonlog.dataset.state = 'valid';
  }} else {
    buttonlog.dataset.state = 'invalid';
  }
}})
</script>
```

All I did here was replace 'password' with 'input'. If this still doesn't work, you could always use onkeydown (replacing 'password' with 'keydown').

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. I was wondering with your first method how I could make it so if the pattern (in this case if the username is 8+ characters AND password is 8+ characters) is true I could change the background color of a button. I want for it to continously check if the pattern has been met(if not the color is gray) and if it has to change the color of the button to lets say yellow and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating the length of the trimmed-username, all you have to do is trim the value and assign a valid flag.

You have various issues with your code. For example, `addEventListener` does not support an event type of `'username'` or `'password'`. Your selectors and CSS selector rules are also incorrect.

If you have an input with an ID of `username`, then the appropriate selector is `#username` (note the leading octothorp).

```js
const
  form = document.forms['login'],
  username = form.elements.username,
  password = form.elements.password,
  buttonlog = document.querySelector('.log');

form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
  const
    currUsername = username.value.trim(),
    currPassword = password.value.trim(),
    usernameIsValid = currUsername.length > 5;

  buttonlog.dataset.state = usernameIsValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
});
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 1fr;
}

button.log[data-state="valid"] {
  background-color: #C9A243;
}

button.log[data-state="invalid"] {
  background-color: #909495;
}
```

```html
<form name="login" onsubmit="return false">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" />

  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />

  <button class="log">Log</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

Event listeners should have an event associated to them, `username` nor `password` are events, you should try with `input` or `keyup` to handle what you want. You may do this in 2 ways, with css or js, but since css require **RegEx** and they are tricky to understand, I'll show you te JS (gods) way

### JS

Using event `input`

```js
let usr = document.getElementById('usr');

usr.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.value !== '') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  } else {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="usr" type="text" placeholder="email" />
```

Comment: The `input` event works better `addEventListener('input',`